# What does this term in a SimBrief flight plan routing mean?

Tags: flight-planning, air-traffic-management, enroute

I checked everywhere and I cannot figure out what the bold sections mean in this flight plan routing I got from SimBrief:

> DTTA/11 **N0430F360** TOBI3C TOBIB UA725 TANIT UM733 OSMAR DCT ALEDI DCT APSUX DCT GILIO DCT NUKNI DCT SOVUB/**N0347F180** Z43 OTGIG OTGI2E LIPZ/04R

I understand that this may be related to some flight level but the first section before the F does not seem to make sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

As shown in [ICAO Doc 4444-ATM/501](https://www.icao.int/EURNAT/Other%20Meetings%20Seminars%20and%20Workshops/FPL%202012%20ICAO%20EUR%20Region%20Plan/Documentation%20related%20to%20FPL%202012%20Amendment/Amendment%201%20Doc4444.EN.pdf),  (PROCEDURES FOR AIR NAVIGATION SERVICES), reference page A2-8, **N0430** and **N0347** (per your question) refers to the flight planned speed (in knots) of the aircraft shown in the flight plan. (e.g., N0430 = 430 knots)

As you note in your question the second section beginning with the "F" refers to the planned Flight Level.

[image]